# Cancel Task in async void

Tags: c#, task, cancellation, cancellationtokensource

Hi I have a listbox Whenever a user selects an item a request is sent to the web Now I want to *cancel* the previous operation when the user selected the item and then start the new operation.

I used the following codes to do this, I wanted to know if these codes work well. Or should I try another way?

```
private CancellationTokenSource ts = new CancellationTokenSource();
private async void Subf2mCore(CancellationToken ct)
{
  HtmlDocument doc = await web.LoadFromWebAsync(url);
   ...
  foreach (var node in doc)
  {
    if (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
      ....
    }
  }
}
```

and i run func this way

```
ts?.Cancel();
ts = new CancellationTokenSource();
Subf2mCore(ts.Token);
```

Comment: Yes, you can cancel `Subf2mCore` execution, but let others (i.e. `Subf2mCore` caller) know it: put it as `private async Task Subf2mCore(CancellationToken ct) {...}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically, you can put it like this, but look: you *fire and forget*, let return `Task` for caller to know if `Subf2mCore` has been *completed*, *failed* or *cancelled*:

```
private async Task Subf2mCore(CancellationToken ct)
{
  HtmlDocument doc = await web.LoadFromWebAsync(url);
   ...
  foreach (var node in doc)
  {
    // Often we cancel by throwing exception: 
    // it's easy to detect that the task is cancelled by catching this exception
    // ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

    // You prefer to cancel manually: 
    // your cancellation can be silent (no exceptions) but it'll be 
    // difficult for caller to detect if task completed or not 
    // (partially completed and cancelled)
    if (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
      ....
    }
  }
}

// If we don't want to cancel 
private async Task Subf2mCore() => Subf2mCore(CancellationToken.None);
```

Usage: do not forget to `Dispose` `CancellationTokenSource` instance:

```
using (CancellationTokenSource ts = new CancellationTokenSource()) {
  ...
  await Subf2mCore(ts.Token);
  ...
}
```

**Edit:** if you want to cancel from *outside*:

```
private CancellationTokenSource ts = null;

...

using (CancellationTokenSource _ts = new CancellationTokenSource()) {
  // previous task (if any) cancellation
  if (null != ts)
    ts.Cancel();

  // let cancel from outside
  ts = _ts;

  try {
    ...
    await Subf2mCore(_ts.Token);
    ...
  }
  finally {
    // task completed, we can't cancel it any more
    ts = null;
  }
}
```

Comment: tnx now i used like this `ts?.Cancel();
                using (ts = new CancellationTokenSource())
                {
                    await Subf2mCore(ts.Token);
                }` and i get this error `System.ObjectDisposedException: 'The CancellationTokenSource has been disposed.'`

Comment: @git: I've edited the answer; we should cancel local `CancellationTokenSource`

Comment: tnx but i get error in this line `_ts = CancellationTokenSource()` cannot be used like a method

Comment: @git: sorry for the typo, I've omitted `new`